# split string using regex

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to use `split()` to get this output:

```
Colour = "Red/White/Blue/Green/Yellow/"
Colour = "Orange"
```

...but could not succeed.  What am I doing wrong?

Basically I am matching the last `/` and splitting the string there.

```
String pattern = "[\\/]$";
String colours = "Red/White/Blue/Green/Yellow/Orange";

Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile(pattern);
String[] result = splitter.split(colours);

for (String colour : result) {
    System.out.println("Colour = \"" + colour + "\"");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get individual colors or just the last color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the string on the **last** `/`. The regex to match the last `/` is:

```
/(?!.*/)
```

[See it on IdeOne](http://www.ideone.com/G1OwM)

Explanation:

```
/       : A literal /
(?!.*/) : Negative lookahead assertion. So the literal / above is matched only 
          if it is not followed by any other /. So it matches only the last /
```

Comment: +1.  Or, if you really have to retain the slash at the end of the first token, you can use `(?<=/(?=[^/]*$))` instead. :D

Comment: @Alan: You are right..looks like OP wants to have the `/` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
int ix = colours.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
String[] result = { colours.substring(0, ix), colours.substring(ix) };
```

(EDIT: corrected to include trailing `/` at end of first string.)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is incorrect, you placed the `$` that says it **must** end with a `/`, remove `$` and it should work fine.

While we are at it, you could just use the [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
String colours = "Red/White/Blue/Green/Yellow/Orange";
String[] result = colours.split("\\/");

for (String colour : result) {
    System.out.println("Colour = \"" + colour + "\"");
}
```

Comment: I think OP wanted the string split into exactly two parts, with the split at the last `/`. You'd have to join all but the last part back together with `/` to get what was required.